# Use sensors like gyro and accelerometer to look around a 360 virtual image?

Tags: android, view

I'd like to create a 360 degree view for my device and use my device to move around and look around me to all points in the view. If you're similar to Yelp's Monocle, I kind of want to do that sort of thing, but instead of looking through the camera I want to look at a panoramic view. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: did you find an a solution for this?

Comment: Not anything that I would now call ideal :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. If you don't know how to use the accelerometer Here there is a quick tutorial:
http://karanbalkar.com/2012/09/tutorial-1-android-accelerometer-demo/

Then you only need to translate the (x,y,z) acceleration into a vector orientation (Simply do some maths).
Take care about screen orientation be sure that you fixed it to portrait or landscape if not the app will be reoriented.

PD: Another tutorial from nvidia website for developer: http://docs.nvidia.com/tegra/data/How_To_Use_the_Android_Accelerometer.html